# Add a command in "SSIS Packages" menu

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I developed an extension to Visual Studio to generate SSIS package.

Now, I want to display the command in the menu "SSIS Packages" :
[image]

But I can't find the GUID and ID of this menu to complete ".vsct" :

```xml
<Groups>
  <Group guid="guidVsixHideCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0000">
    <Parent guid="???" id="???"/>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

Can you tell me the GUID/ID of the menu "SSIS Package"?

Comment: Does this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-commands?view=vs-2022#to-locate-a-command-definition ) can help you to find a command definition

Comment: Yes, now I need to find the `.vsct` from SSIS extension.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT, do you know where is `.vsct` from SSIS extension?

Comment: Check this folder %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Visual Studio version>\Extensions\  can you find the .vsct file of SSIS extension?

Comment: Not here. [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) isn't standard extension.

Comment: Maybe it's my search method that fail. I try to find a occurrence of `SSIS` in file with the extension `.vsct`.